# Javascript animation menu bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I just coded a menu that has an animation in javascript. The script works as it should but I don't like that if you navegate throught the items from up to down, the menu gets really buggy and the texts start to display like crazy. A possible solution is, that when the mouse enters to a list item, it has to have a certain delay for the animation to start (for example, you must have the mouse there 3 seconds, if not, nothing happens). setTimeout won't do it, because it will execute the animation anyway. I am wondering if there is a work around this, because i can't come up with any.

this is the code that does the animation:

```
$( '.menu li a' ).hover( function(){
        var el = $(this);
        var numero = el.parent().index();
        el.animate({
            'height': height[numero]+'px'
        }, 'slow');
    }, function(){
        $(this).animate({
            'height': 0
        }, 'slow');
    });
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/N54ap/)

I am trying to attempt this without using css Transitions. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to stop the previous animation queue by using `.stop()`,

```
    $( '.menu li a' ).hover( function(){
        var el = $(this);
        var numero = el.parent().index();
        el.stop().animate({
            'height': height[numero]+'px'
        }, 'slow');
    }, function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({
            'height': 0
        }, 'slow');
    });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N54ap/1/)

Comment: The moment when you forget the .stop() method. It worked as i wanted!.

I also found this [plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) but i didn't want to load a plugin just for that.